# Stop subnav from closing when hovering off main menu and onto subnav

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, hover

I have a subnav fading in and a fullwidth background for the subnav animating in when link in the main nav is hovered. How do I keep the sub nav open when the hovering off of the main nav and onto the subnav. The subnav closes when you're not over the main menu item.

```
                <nav class="header-menu menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="nav-text">Expertise</span>
                            <span class="icon-down-arrow-small "></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Meet our Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Our Process</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="nav-text">Projects</span>
                            <span class="icon-down-arrow-small "></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Meet our Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Our Process</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Our Process</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Our Process</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Insights</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Careers</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

```
  $(".nav-text").mouseenter(function(){

                var that = this;
                var subNavHeight = $(that).parent().siblings('.sub-menu').outerHeight();

                $(that).parent().parent().siblings().children('.sub-menu').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 100);// fade out all sub-menus


                $('.menu-expand').stop().animate({height:subNavHeight},200, "linear", function(){
                    $(that).parent().siblings('.sub-menu').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 200);



                });

            });
```

[image]

Comment: From the code you posted, I can't reproduce the issue about `sub-menu` closing. But have a look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/bKpqzQ) and tell me if that works for you. ;)

Comment: I did add the mouseleave the ".menu-expand" div which does work well but when you mouseleave the ".nav-text" with out entering the ".menu-expand" div it doesn't close the menu.

Comment: And if you hover off ".sub-menu" without hovering ".menu-expand" it doesn't close either. I guess the question how to have multiple mouseleave points?

Comment: okay... So the trick will be to use `setTimeout()` to "order a close" in a given time... But revoque that "order" on a certain condition. I made another version of the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zaqwmE)

Comment: Thank you!! Its definitely closer. Its still a little buggy. Sometimes mousing from ".nav-text" to ".sub-menu" closes it and mousing from ".nav-text"  to ".menu-expand" closes it also. I added a call back for the open close function.